# Divide each row by a constant and create a new column

Tags: r, divide

I want to create a new column named percentage and add it to by dataframe. This column should consist of each row divided by the constant 13197 and multiplied with 100. Can anyone help with this task?

Here is the head of my dataframe.

```
   Var1 Freq
1 01085    6
2 01602   34
3 01845   31
4 03824    1
5 04011   16
6 04102    2
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow @Amy. You should show some effort to solve your problem before asking for help. That's how it works on stackoverflow, and you'll be able to get good help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

df <- mutate(df, perc = Freq/sum(Freq) * 100)
```

This will avoid you having to divide by a constant (rather it divides by the sum of the column named "Freq").

If you want the constant, the code would be:

```
df <- mutate(df, perc = Freq/13197 * 100)
```

Of course, instead of using the package, you could do this in base R with

```
df$perc = df$Freq/13197 * 100)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I actually need the constant.

Answer (score 2):

`df$percent <- 100*df$freq/13197`

Comment: Thank you! I get this error Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, percent, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 241

Comment: I believe the issue is that your data column name is `Freq` with a capital F, and this answer uses `freq` with a lower case f. You will need to adapt the code to use your actual column name.

Answer (score 1):

```
df$percentage <-   (df$Var1) * (df$Freq) * (100) / (13197)
```

You can refer to the new column directly and assign it this way. I'm assuming you need to multiply the (df$Var1) by it's frequency.

Comment: Thank you  very much! Problem solved! But there is no need to multiply the Var1. It was surprisingly easy :)